# Oracle SQL take duplicate results out off some columns

Tags: sql, oracle

My data has categories and subcategories in separate tables. When I write a query to join them I get the below table with the category rows repeating:

```
|  Col1 |    Col2   |   Col3     | Col 4 | 
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat1 | Cat1 Data | Subcat 1.1 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat1 | Cat1 Data | Subcat 1.2 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat1 | Cat1 Data | Subcat 1.3 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat2 | Cat2 Data | Subcat 2.1 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat2 | Cat2 Data | Subcat 2.2 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat2 | Cat2 Data | Subcat 2.3 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
```

Is there any way to get this to print out with the main category showing only once?

```
|  Col1 |    Col2   |   Col3     | Col 4 | 
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat1 | Cat1 Data | Subcat 1.1 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|       |           | Subcat 1.2 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|       |           | Subcat 1.3 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|  Cat2 | Cat2 Data | Subcat 2.1 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|       |           | Subcat 2.2 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
|       |           | Subcat 2.3 | Etc   |
|-------|-----------|------------|-------|
```

Searching online only returns references to using distinct or groupby which don't really seem to fit the use case. I understand that the answer here is usually "use the front end tool" but that's not really option in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this does seem to do what you want

**Data (DDL)**

```
create table example(
   col1 varchar(100),
   col2 varchar(100),
   col3 varchar(100),
   col4 varchar(100)
);

insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat1','Cat1 Data', 'Subcat 1.1', 'Etc');
insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat1','Cat1 Data', 'Subcat 1.2', 'Etc');
insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat1','Cat1 Data', 'Subcat 1.3', 'Etc');
insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat2','Cat2 Data', 'Subcat 2.3', 'Etc');
insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat2','Cat2 Data', 'Subcat 2.3', 'Etc');
insert into example(col1,col2,col3,col4) values('Cat2','Cat2 Data', 'Subcat 2.3', 'Etc');
```

**SQL query (the answer)**

```
select
   CASE WHEN lag(col1) over (partition by null order by col1) = col1 THEN null ELSE col1 END col1,
   CASE WHEN lag(col2) over (partition by null order by col2) = col2 THEN null ELSE col2 END col2,
   col3, col4
From example
```

Comment: Interesting solution. By the way, looks like `partition by null` can be omitted

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/def46f/1

Answer (score 1):

You are better off with the repetition.  But, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by ?) = 1
             then col1
        end) as col1
       (case when row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by ?) = 1
             then col2
        end) as col2,
       . . .
from t
order by col1, col2, ?;
```

Note that the `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering -- what defines "first" for each row.

It is very important that you include the `order by` in the outer query.  SQL result sets (like tables) are *unordered*.  Without the `order by`, the rows can be returned in any order, but ordering is important in this case.